# Multiple async queries in cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cql3

I have a tornado web application, for tracking some data (It uses cassandra storage and cql for querying). It does two things:

1. Add a record in one column family.
2. Increase some counters in a batch in few column families.

In the example below if you look at track method of Storage class, it does two async queries and first async query does success or error callback. On my dev environment I see both the async queries are executed properly. Will this have issues on production (I will be getting more than 5000 hits per second from day one as I will be integrating it into an already existing applications). I did test it with Apache Benchmark to do concurrent requests and don't see any issue. I just want to be sure. Also is there a better way to handle scenarios like this and will there be any performance implications?

Example below:

```
class SomeClass(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def collect_data(self):
        return {}  # has some data

    def on_success(self):
        # has logic here
        self.finish()

    def on_error(self):
        # has logic here
        self.finish()

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        # some code here
        Storage.track(self.collect_data(), self.onsuccess, self.onerror)

class Storage(object):
    @classmethod
    def connect(cls):
        cluster = Cluster()
        cls._session = cluster.connect()

    @classmethod
    def track(cls, data, success_callback, error_callback):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_session'):
            cls.connect()
        cls._session.execute_async(*insert query*).add_callbacks(success_callback, error_callback)
        cls._session.execute_async(*some batch queries to increase counters*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about some discussion about performance and different patterns [here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/performance.html). Your approach seems reasonable in this context. I would add that it would be a good idea to use prepared statements, which you would prepare and keep around for the lifetime of session.

> Will this have issues on production [...][?]

This depends on a lot of things, including your environment, deployment footprint, etc. The best thing you can do is benchmark